# Query com count retornando vazio

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT 
  numero,
  sistema,
  status,
  date_first_queued
  FROM 
    ocorrencias 
      HAVING DATE(date_first_queued) between  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND CURDATE()
      AND  sistema = '17'
```

Ela me retorna os registros perfeitamente, mais ai quero usa junto com ela um `count` só que ai ela retorna vazia, segue minha consulta com `count`:

```
SELECT
 COUNT(numero), 
  numero,
  sistema,
  status,
  date_first_queued
  FROM 
    ocorrencias 
      HAVING DATE(date_first_queued) between  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND CURDATE()
      AND  sistema = '17'
```

Inclusive preciso usar o `group by` mais quando coloco o `group by`  da o seguinte erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o count retorna sempre uma linha, e não varias linhas. Com este pensamento não percebo o porquê de querer as restantes colunas. O GROUP BY deverá vir antes de order by se pretender order by primeiro deverá fazer uma subquery.

Comment: Para ser mais facil pode colocar um exemplo por exemplo http://sqlfiddle.com/ para termos dados para manipular.

Comment: Segue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec6a9/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando uma função de agrupamento é utilizada (SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX, ...) se existe mais um campo além da campo que está sendo agrupado, DEVE ser adicionada uma cláusula GROUP BY, sempre antes de ORDER BY (quando existir).

No seu caso, está faltando adicionar os demais campos além do campo COUNT na cláusula GROUP BY, além desta estar no local errado.

A query correta seria:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(numero) contador, 
  numero,
  sistema,
  status,
  date_first_queued
FROM ocorrencias 
WHERE DATE(date_first_queued) between  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND CURDATE() AND  sistema = '17'
GROUP BY
  numero, 
  sistema,
  status,
  date_first_queued
```

Ou seja, você quer contar quantas registros existem na tabela OCORRENCIAS com o mesmo `numero, sistema, status, date_first_queued`.

Comment: Só não faz sentido GROUP BY numero (porque é um AUTO_INCREMENT), mas boa resposta

Comment: Verdade @TiagoGomes. Coloquei somente porque eram os campos que ele queria retornar na consulta. Quando respondi ainda não tinha o exemplo no http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec6a9/1. Obrigado pela observação.